# Chosen select box with multiple selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am filling a chosen text-box with countries on chosen drop down of Regions.but when I remove a region from Region drop down all selected countries vanishes. I have updated the chosen with

```
success:function(data){
    if(typeof(data)!='undefined' && data!='' && data!=null){
        var html = [];
        for(i in data){
            html.push('<option value="'+i+'" >'+data[i]+'</option>');
        }
        $('#geo_country').html(html.join(''));
        $('#geo_country').trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    $('#loading-spinner-geo_region').hide();
}
```

but don't know how to get the remaining selected countries please help ?

NOTE:- countries text-box is dependent on Regions drop down.

Comment: can you please share your mark up code and share jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: I think it would be more clear now

Comment: so after removing region you are calling above code to add countries in `$('#geo_country')`, right? so do you want to keep previous options in `$('#geo_country')` and add new ones?

Comment: I mean to say when a region is removed its associated countries should be removed from $('#geo_country') and remaining selected countries should be remain selected.

Comment: So please where are the selected countries and how it works. Please share jsfiddle link to get more clarity.